# Connect two labels to one outlet

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview

Now I understand that this question has been asked before, but the answers were unsatisfactory. My issue is that I have a view controller with a view and stuff in it including a label. I added a bunch of code for it and now I'm expanding on it. I now have an issue where I've decided to add another UIView to my interface and it has a label and that label is going to function EXACTLY like a label I have in my first UIView. My problem is that I don't want to have to go in my view controller method and add another line of code each time I manipulate that first label. Is there anyway I can link another label to my initial IBOutlet I have set for my first label? Or do I have to go in my code and add an extra line of code everytime I manipulate that first label?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Basically the simple answer is no. Whether you use outlets or an outlet collection or tags or whatever, you ultimately have *one* reference in your code to *one* label in your interface, and *another* reference in your code to *another* reference in your interface. You can compress your *mode of expression* so as to cycle readily through those references (as suggested in a different answer), but the basic fact is inescapable that, ultimately, the only way to "talk to" a label is through the one reference that points to *that* label and to that label alone.

The only way of getting around that is not to use direct references at all. For example, a single message *can* be sent to multiple recipients by using an NSNotification. So you could have two instances of some UILabel subclass of your own, and "shout" to both instances *simultaneously* by posting a notification from your view controller - the notification is then *automatically* passed on to both labels, because you have arranged beforehand for them to register for it.

Similarly, another alternative is that you could use key-value observing so that a change in your view controller is *automatically* propagated to both labels automatically because they "observe" the change, meaning they are sent notifications - really just an inverted form of NSNotification. (If this were Mac OS X, you could make a simpler, safer version of this arrangement by using "bindings".)

However, I really cannot actually recommend that approach. The truth is that we still live in an excruciatingly primitive world of text-based programming, one line at a time, one command at a time, one reference at a time, and we must just bite the bullet and get on with it.

Comment: Thanks, I'll bite the bullet and add another line of code.

Comment: Hey matt. What if I want one class to represent 2 different views created in storyboard? Suppose this class is doing some common stuff with some label, I change the class property of those views to my class in interface builder, which is fine. But then when I connect one, the next one doesn't connect to the outlet since it is already busy. What's the reason?

Comment: @frangulya, did you also drag outlets from both views from `storyboard` to the `shared class`? Sometimes storyboard bugs up, but you can use `assistant editor` to see your `shared class`, when your `storyboard` is open. Just make sure you drag outlets from both views it handles! You could also drag outlets to a parent class of the `shared class`, if you have one. But, you know, honestly, this doesn't look like it's a good approach to me. I'd still recomment you to extract your view elsewhere..

Answer (score 7):

It depends on what you want to do to that label. If you're looking to change some of the attributes of the label in the same way (e.g., font, text colour, alignment) then you can put both labels in an `IBOutletCollection` and iterate over the collection in your view controller.

If you want to have different data in the label, but other attributes the same, then you'll need a separate `IBOutlet` for that label.

You can combine the two techniques as well. e.g.

(interface)

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *firstName;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *lastName;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutletCollection(UILabel) NSArray *labels;
```

(implementation)

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
  [super viewDidLoad];

  for (UILabel *aLabel in self.labels) {
    // Set all label in the outlet collection to have center aligned text.
    [aLabel setTextAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
  }

  [self.firstName setText:@"First Name"];
  [self.lastName setText:@"Last Name"];
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I realized that after a search of my view controller file, I only had 18 uses of my label, which is a lot less than I thought, so I'll just go the multiple outlet route.

Comment: This is a pretty good answer, but the *If you want to have different data...* part is incorrect. An IBOutletCollection is simply a collection of objects -- there's nothing that requires you to treat every object in the collection the same.

Comment: @Caleb That's fair, but if you're iterating over a collection of objects and need to determine the difference between them (e.g. using magic numbers in the .tag property, or looking at the specific Class of one of the objects) then it is probably better for code clarity to use separate properties for the objects.

Answer (score 0):

**Swift 3, Xcode 8**

- Create a prototype cell with objects
- then add another prototype
- It will copy the objects from the first prototype cell.
- The new objects will be connected to the same IBOutlet

Also, copy and pasting objects maintains IBActions, but does not maintain IBOutlets.

I hope this answers your question, as none of the other answers had this work around.