# iOS: Styling multiple textfields

Tags: objective-c, ios7

I have multiple UITextFields with the same/similar styling but I'm styling them individually. How would I style them all in on go?

example of what I'm doing now:

```
textfield1.layer.borderWith = 2;
textfield2.layer.borderWith = 2;
textfield3.layer.borderWith = 2;
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Connect two labels to one outlet](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22291569/connect-two-labels-to-one-outlet)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's something I've used in the past:

```
UITextField * textField1;
UITextField * textField2;
UITextField * textField3;

for (UITextField * textField in @[textField1, textField2, textField3]) {
    textField.layer.borderWidth = 2;
}
```

If you're doing extensive edits to create a highly customized textField, it might be better to use a subclass.  If you've just got a few additions you want applied to each textfield, this should be fine.

As per your request, because I'm feeling generous.  Here's an example of a UITextField subclass.

MyTextField.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface MyTextField : UITextField

@end
```

MyTextField.m

```
#import "MyTextField.h"

@implementation MyTextField

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        // Initialization code
        self.layer.borderWidth = 2;

        // Blue For Demonstration
        self.layer.borderColor = [UIColor blueColor].CGColor;

        // add whatever else you want to customize here ....
    }
    return self;
}

////////

////// ** Include Custom Methods You Might Need **

////////

@end
```

Then, in whatever ViewController or View you want to use it, add this:

```
#import "MyTextField.h"
```

Then, you can launch MyTextField class Textfields like this:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

    MyTextField * textField1 = [MyTextField new];
    textField1.frame = CGRectMake(10, 30, 100, 30);
    [self.view addSubview:textField1];

    MyTextField * textField2 = [MyTextField new];
    textField2.frame = CGRectMake(10, 70, 100, 30);
    [self.view addSubview:textField2];

    MyTextField * textField3 = [MyTextField new];
    textField3.frame = CGRectMake(10, 110, 100, 30);
    [self.view addSubview:textField3];
}
```

And you'll get this:

[image: UITextField Subclass Demo]

Comment: Thx, could you please include a quick subclass example

Answer (score 0):

How about --

```
for (UIView *view in [self.view subviews]) {
    if ([view isKindOfClass:[UITextField class]]) {
        UITextField *textField = (UITextField *)view;
        textField.layer.borderWidth = 2.0;
    }
}
```

That way you will not even have to have outlets of textFields in the view. But this is, of course, only applicable if you want to apply same styles to every textField in the view.

Answer (score 0):

If the textfields have outlets, create an IBOutletCollection like so in your .h:

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutletCollection(UITextField) NSArray *textFields;
```

Then, in your .m:

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {

    [super viewWillAppear:animated];

    for(UITextField *textField in self.textFields) {
        textfield.layer.borderWith = 2;
        // add more here as needed
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure why you're getting that error. It works fine for me.

Comment: Did you hook up all the textFields (and only textFields) in InterfaceBuilder to this OutletCollection?

Comment: The only time I get this is if I misspell UITextField in IBOutletCollection(UITextField) (i.e. UItextField or UITextfield). I'd double-check your syntax. I'm looking at a project right now with the exact syntax I posted that works great.

Comment: Sorry, you are absolutely correct.. It was a dumb mistake/typo I didn't catch.

Comment: No problem. Happens to me all the time. Haha. I'm glad to hear it works for you.